# Is meat and bone meal still used to feed livestock?

Tags: livestock-industry, commercial-farming

It looks like [meat and bone meal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_and_bone_meal) can cause mad cow disease.

I understand that feeding it to pets like dogs and cats is not such a big problem since humans (usually) don't eat pets.

But is meat and bone meal still used in any country to feed horses, sheep, goats, rabbits, poultry etc?